# How to setup gimp to recognize input device changes inside of painting area?

Tags: gimp, drawing-tablet

Gimp only recognizes a change in input device (from pen to mouse) when the cursor leaves the painting area.

If I paint with my pen, stop and then move my mouse it will move the cursor but the brush will still be the one from the pen (and the brush area will stay in place) and only if the cursor (now controlled by the mouse) leaves the paint area it will switch fully switch to mouse-mode (now the mouse controls the brush, and the brush is set to what ever was selected for the mouse.)

I would like gimp to switch instantly so I do not have to leave the paint area first.

Background: My tablet supports touch (in that if i use my fingers, it sends mouse (not pen) signals to gimp. - And in this touch(mouse)-mode zooming gestures work in gimp. But if I always have to move the cursor outside the painting area for gimp to recognize the change fully, that is very annoying.

Sidenote: Gimp instantly recognizes the change from pen to eraser (no need to leave the painting area) only the change to mouse is not instant.

Comment: Sorry - prboaboy that capability is missing in the software. It will have a higher probability of being addressed if you can fill in a bug repot/enhancement request for that at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/ .The reason for such an outstanding UX shortcome is that there are few GIMP developers, and fewer still do have appropriate drawing hardware like atablet with multiple tips.

Comment: Just to clarify: Two tips do actually work, it's only when switching back to default pointing device (by using touch on the wacom pad, or moving the mouse) that the device change is only corretly recognized if you leave the painting area. - Thanks for the tip, I will file a bugreport later.

Comment: Several people on the #gimp IRC channels have reported that this works fine for them - and the question is lacking essential information like what GIMP version is being used, or what tablet model.